# casting sockaddr_storage as sockaddr_in for inet_ntop

Tags: c, sockets

I am trying to cast a sockaddr_storage to a sockadd_in, so that i can print out the source ip address of a datagram packet,
i do not seem to be able to get the cast correct,

```
struct sockaddr_storage  peer_addr;


getnameinfo((struct sockaddr *) &peer_add
                peer_addrlen,
                hostbuff, sizeof(hostbuff),
                NULL, 0, NI_NAMEREQD);


inet_ntop(AF_INET, (((struct sockaddr_in *)peer_addr).sin_addr), ipbuff, INET_ADDRSTRLEN);
```

when i try to cast the structure to a sockaddr_in, i either get 'cannot convert to pointer', or when i remove the dereferance i get 'conversion to non scaler type requested'.

I have tried alot of combinations and simply don't understand where i am going wrong.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
inet_ntop(peer_addr->ss_family, &(((struct sockaddr_in *)peer_addr)->sin_addr), ipbuff, INET_ADDRSTRLEN);
```

should work. But consider to use `getnameinfo()` instead, which is the more modern
interface:

```
char host[NI_MAXHOST];
getnameinfo((struct sockaddr *)peer_addr, peer_addr->ss_len, host, sizeof(host), NULL, 0, NI_NUMERICHOST);
```

works for both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses.

---

*Update* according to the changed types in the question: This is a complete example
that should compile without warnings:

```
int socket = ...;

struct sockaddr_storage peer_addr;
socklen_t peer_addrlen;
char host[NI_MAXHOST];

ssize_t amount;
char buffer[1000];
amount = recvfrom(socket, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&peer_addr, &peer_addrlen);
getnameinfo((struct sockaddr *)&peer_addr, peer_addrlen, host, sizeof(host), NULL, 0, NI_NUMERICHOST);
```

Or, using `inet_ntop()`:

```
char ipbuff[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
inet_ntop(peer_addr.ss_family, &(((struct sockaddr_in *)&peer_addr)->sin_addr), ipbuff, INET_ADDRSTRLEN);
```

Comment: i thought getnameinfo() returned the hostname of the address?

Comment: @Babbleshack: See "man getnameinfo" for the NI_NUMERICHOST flag: Return the address in numeric form, as if calling inet_ntop(3), instead of a host name.

Comment: The portable way is not to use `peer_addr->ss_family` (which isn't even known at least on my system), but to use the real size of the allocated structure.

Comment: @Babbleshack: May I ask why you "unaccepted" the answer? Does it not work anymore? - Of course glglgl is right that using the actual sockaddr length (e.g. as returned by recvfrom()) is the more portable way, but that should not make my answer completely wrong. - And it confusing if you change the question. Originally, peer_addr was a *pointer* to a struct sockaddr_storage, therefore my answer assumed that.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks your answer reflects my working code. I have reaccepted your answer.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> struct sockaddr_storage  *  peer_addr;
>
>
> getnameinfo((struct sockaddr *) &peer_add
>                 peer_addrlen,
>                 hostbuff, sizeof(hostbuff),
>                 NULL, 0, NI_NAMEREQD);
> ```

Here you are mixing up stuff.

`getnameinfo()` indeed takes a `struct sockaddr*` as its first parameter, but what you try to do here won't work: `peer_addr` is a `struct sockaddr_storage *`, you take its address - which is a `struct sockaddr_storage **`, and try to cast this. That won't work.

I don't know where your `peer_addr` comes from, but

- either it should be a `struct sockaddr_storage` (I don't think there is a need to have a pointer to a `struct sockaddr_storage` somewhere)
- or it is really a pointer, and you should pass `(struct sockaddr *) peer_addr` - without the `&` - to `getnameinfo()`.

Another point: The second parameter for `getnameinfo()` is supposed to be the "real" size of the address struct you are inputting.

Comment: when i try to do that i get a compilation error, when i use my original code, my program works as expected.

does this mean i have 'undefined behaviour'

Comment: @Babbleshack I don't know what that meas as I don't know which compilation error you get. But it is very likely that you get UB, as a cast might hide and shadow problems.

Comment: When i remove the dereferance from sockaddr, i get 'conversion to non scaler type' error