# Convert hexadecimal value to ip address of type string in C.

Tags: c, string, ip, hex

i have a hex value say for example 0x0a010203 and i want to convert it to a string such that after conversion it should be like "10.1.2.3",How to extract the individual fields from the hex value ?

Comment: you can use loop extract non-zero number one by one,then turn it into decimal number.or you can use library function combination to solve your problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fill a `struct in_addr` and use [`inet_ntoa()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/inet_addr.html) ("Internet address to ASCII string"):

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>

struct in_addr addr;
addr.s_addr = htonl(0x0a010203); // s_addr must be in network byte order 
char *s = inet_ntoa(addr); // --> "10.1.2.3"
```

Note that the string returned by `inet_ntoa()` may point to static data that may be overwritten by subsequent calls. That is no problem if it is just printed and then not
used anymore. Otherwise it would be necessary to *duplicate* the string.

Comment: Is there a similar method for IPv6?

Comment: @AthulSukumaran: `inet_ntop` or `getnameinfo`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/20130662/1187415 for an example.

Comment: Thanks @Martin. But for ipv6, in6_addr stores value as unsigned char[16]. inet_ntop expects this as argument. My question was specifically about hex value. Also htonl doesn't seem to work for such large hex.

Answer (score 6):

You can use bit masking and bit shifts, eg:

```
unsigned int val = 0x0a010203;
printf("%d.%d.%d.%d",
     (val & 0xFF000000) >> 24,
     (val & 0x00FF0000) >> 16,
     (val & 0x0000FF00) >> 8,
     val & 0x000000FF);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
unsigned ip = 0x0A0A0A50;

printf("%u.%u.%u.%u\n",ip >> 24 & 0xFF
                      ,ip >> 16 & 0xFF
                      ,ip >>  8 & 0xFF
                      ,ip       & 0xFF);

Output: 10.10.10.80
```

Comment: Though we thank you for your answer, it would be better if it provided additional value on top of the other answers. In this case, your answer does not provide additional value: it's just a tiny variation on [jkyako's answer](/a/23577822/4850040). If a previous answer was helpful to you, you should vote it up instead of repeating the same information.