# Wrong IP and port from server socket

Tags: c++, c, linux, sockets, gcc

When I write a code like below, the reported ip and port of the peer is correct:

```
int main(){
    int server = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
    struct sockaddr_in addr;    
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(8080);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    bind(server,(struct sockaddr *)&addr,sizeof addr);
    listen(server,5);
    struct sockaddr_storage inc_adrs;
    socklen_t inc_len;
    int client = accept(server, (struct sockaddr *) &inc_adrs,&inc_len);
    struct sockaddr_in *inc_adr = (struct sockaddr_in *) &inc_adrs;    
    char ip [INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
    inet_ntop(AF_INET,&(inc_adr->sin_addr),ip,INET_ADDRSTRLEN);
    printf("Connection from %s port %d\n",ip,ntohs(inc_adr->sin_port));
    return 0;
}
```

And for example I connect to it using nc on my local machine :

```
#nc 127.0.0.1 8080
```

And the ouput is:

```
Connection from 127.0.0.1 port 55112
```

But if I just put them in another block like "if" or "while" the program reports wrong ip and port:

```
int main(){
    if (1){
        int server = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
        struct sockaddr_in addr;    
        addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        addr.sin_port = htons(8080);
        addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
        bind(server,(struct sockaddr *)&addr,sizeof addr);
        listen(server,5);
        struct sockaddr_storage inc_adrs;
        socklen_t inc_len;
        int client = accept(server, (struct sockaddr *) &inc_adrs,&inc_len);
        struct sockaddr_in *inc_adr = (struct sockaddr_in *) &inc_adrs;    
        char ip [INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
        inet_ntop(AF_INET,&(inc_adr->sin_addr),ip,INET_ADDRSTRLEN);
        printf("Connection from %s port %d\n",ip,ntohs(inc_adr->sin_port));
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Sample output:

```
Connection from 253.127.0.0 port 32323
```

I compile it with "gcc code.c -o code" on linux x64.
It is very strange and I don't know how it is possible. Any idea?

Comment: no need to use sockaddr_storage, immediately use a sockaddr_in. Check the values inside that struct before using inet_ntop.

Comment: Also read this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20130415/casting-sockaddr-storage-as-sockaddr-in-for-inet-ntop Don't use inet_ntop.

Comment: 1. Use SO_REUSEADDR: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24194961/how-do-i-use-setsockoptso-reuseaddr
2. check return values from `socket`, `bind`, `listen`, `accept`. If one of these fail you get garbage down the code.

Comment: @PhilipStuyck I did what you said the problem persists. This seems impossible that "if block" changes the behavior of program. Why is the problem happening while in "if"

Comment: @fukanchik This code has been simplified to take less space. The main code contains error checking and also SO_REUSEADDR with no error reported. But what is happening is making me crazy

Comment: @CS. So this is not the real code? Then I'm not going to bother debugging it.

Comment: @melpomene the problem really exists even in this code

Comment: @fukanchik How do you know it's the same problem?

Comment: @fukanchik Same thing happens. This code behaves differently while in the "if" block.

Comment: @melpomene I tried also this code and what I said happens. I can solve the problem by using different APIs but the only thing I wanna know is WHY is this happening? It seems an implementation fault in APIs and heap related or I don't know

Comment: @CS. Aside from the missing initialization of `inc_len` (which is *required*, that is a bug on your part), and the complete lack of error handling (which you should never omit), the rest of the code is fine. The only way I can see an added `if` block breaking the code is if your compiler is broken and producing bad codegen. The more likely culprit is that an uninitialized `inc_len` picks up a random value from the stack and causes `accept()` to fail, and you then pass garbage to `inet_ntop()`. Even your original code without the `if` block is susceptible to that issue.

Comment: @CS. fix your code bug, add error checking, and try again. If the problem continues, edit your question to show your latest code, you are likely still doing something wrong with it. This is too simple a problem for it to likely be caused by a compiler codegen bug.

Comment: @RemyLebeau As I said I fixed the code myself but wanted to know what is happening behind the scene. As currently I don't have time to use a debugger and analyze the program assembly I asked the question here. I should mention also the this code (which you call buggy) always works correctly outside this block or in another function but main.

Comment: @CS.: You are passing garbage into `accept()` to begin with.  Anything beyond that is undefined behavior since this code is not doing ANY error handling. If you don't want to spend time properly debugging the code, then at least include the value of `inc_len` in the app's output, you will likely see a pattern when things fail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, looks like the problem is in how you use `man 2 accept`:

> The `addrlen` argument is a value-result argument: the caller **must initialize** it to contain the size (in bytes) of the structure pointed to by addr; on return it will contain the actual size of the peer address.
>
> The returned address is truncated if the buffer provided is too small; in this case, `addrlen` will return a value greater than was supplied to the call.

With the following fix **plus** SO_REUSEADDR, your code works fine:

```
    struct sockaddr_storage inc_adrs;
    socklen_t inc_len = sizeof( inc_adrs );
```

Also, do not forget to check result values from `socket`, `bind`, `listen`, `accept`.

```
./a.out
Connection from 127.0.0.1 port 11111
---
nc 127.0.0.1 8080 -p 11111

Connection from 192.168.0.1 port 11111
---
nc 192.168.0.1 8080 -p 11111
```

You are using `struct sockaddr_storage inc_adrs;` after `accept` can possibly (depending on random value in inc_len):

- copy full value into inc_adrs
- copy incomplete value into inc_adrs
- never touch into inc_adrs at all if `inc_len` happened to be zero.

For example in my case with `if` `inc_len` is zero. `inc_adrs` remains untouched and contains some garbage:

```
inc_adrs = {ss_family = 0, __ss_align = 234832925920,
            __ss_padding = "@\300\377\377\377\177\000\000G\004I\255\066\000\000\000X...
```

this garbage depends on how the compiler allocates values on stack and what previous code (including glibc) will do to your stack.

For example same value without `if`:

```
1: inc_len = 54 <<--- this one is unitialized!!!!
2: inc_adrs = {ss_family = 49240, __ss_align = 4294967296,
             __ss_padding = "\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\034\00
```

as you can see `inc_len` happens to be 54 which is more than enough for `accept` to save sockaddr_in and hence this case works as if everything is okay.

The difference between `if` and `not-if` cases:

```
-       leaq    -52(%rbp), %rdx
-       leaq    -208(%rbp), %rcx
+       leaq    -180(%rbp), %rdx
+       leaq    -176(%rbp), %rcx
        movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
        movq    %rcx, %rsi
        movl    %eax, %edi
        call    accept
```

So it works correctly only by chance. You can simulate the same with `random`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

srand(time(NULL));
...
socklen_t inc_len = random() % (sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)*2)
```

this will fill `inc_adrs` 50% of time and 5% not touch it.

Comment: Thanks for replying. But I didn't get the answer I was looking for. As I said in the comments I could solve the problem by other ways but I wanted to know WHY this happens. Why this code works outside of "if" or any other scope like "while" but not inside. As this must NOT make a problem. I wanted to know what is happening here

Comment: That is what debuggers are for.  Have you tried debugging the code and inspecting the value of `inc_len` before calling `accept()`, and inspecting the content of `inc_adrs` and the value of `inc_len` after `accept()` exits? Did you try inspecting what you are passing to `inet_ntop()`?  Garbage in, garbage out.

Comment: @RemyLebeau No I have not. But how can it depend on a single "if" block in the way outside of "if" it always works correctly?

Comment: After you edited your answer I agree more and I suspect that without "if" most of the time (if not always) the stack is filled in a way which inc_len gets an "acceptable" value!

Comment: @fukanchik Yes the only thing is that what causes the program not to perform randomly ? As I said every time I get correct output while code is outside if block. Seems it needs more assembly analysis. Thank you

Comment: @CS: "*For example in my case with `if` `inc_len` is zero. **`inc_adrs` remains untouched and contains some garbage**:*" - ALWAYS INITIALIZE YOUR VARIABLES! You MUST initialize `inc_len` before calling `accept()` so it knows how large `inc_adrs` really is. But even then, you should get in the habit of zeroing out structures before filling them. Had you done that, your output would more likely have been `Connection from 0.0.0.0 port 0` instead of random garbage. That would have been your first clue that `accept()` was not populating `inc_adrs`.